# Nutch 1.3: change User-Agent

Tags: user-agent, nutch

I need to change the user-agent string for each crawled domain. I use standard Nutch crawl utility code, it crawls one domain per time. It's being started in multithreading mode to crawl many domains. I need to pass to domain string [botname]+domainID to, but I'm unsure how to implement it?

Answer (score 1):

Since the user agent is manifested in the config file (nutch-site.xml) there is no possibility to change that for a certain domain.

I suggest that you create an instance of nutch for each domain you want to crawl. Within each instance you set the url-filter, seed url and user agent matching the domain you want to crawl.

This should allow you to execute each crawl with custom settings.

cheers mana